# Query in Open Financial Framework (F2.js)

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to use open F2 js (f2.min.js) to communicate to a third party and get the results . I am finding it difficult to get going . Any help would be appreciated . In the following html , I am trying to print a "Hello world" through F2.js but getting error which says com_openf2_examples_javascript_helloworld is not declared.

html:

div class="f2-app-container com_openf2_examples_javascript_helloworld"

manifest.js:

```
    F2_jsonpCallback_com_openf2_examples_javascript_helloworld({
    "scripts":[
        "../appclass.js"
    ],
    "styles":[],
    "apps":[
        {
            "html":[
                '<div>',
                    '<div class="f2-app-view" data-f2-view="home">',
                        '<p>Hello World! Test modals:</p>',
                        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default testAlert">Alert Modal</a>&nbsp;',
                        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default testConfirm">Confirm Modal</a>',
                    '</div>',
                '</div>'
            ].join("")
        }
    ]
})
```

Hello.js:

```
var _appConfig = {
    appId: 'com_openf2_examples_javascript_helloworld',
    manifestUrl: 'manifest.js'
};

$(function(){
    alert("test");
    F2.init();
    F2.registerApps(_appConfig);
});
```

Comment: And where do you include this framework?

Comment: If you're still at the beginning stage of the framework, have you managed to get the Hello World sample in the official GitHub repository working? https://github.com/OpenF2/F2/tree/master/examples/apps/JavaScript/HelloWorld

Comment: I was able to run the index.html file under /examples/ folder and got the sample apps working.But when I try to test Helloworld separately , I am unable to run it .

Comment: I am including this framework in Free marker templates(.ftl) files in the application